# How to emulate passing a function as an argument in Android

Tags: java, android, api

I am porting an API wrapper from iOS to Android. In the iOS wrapper, we have a very large class that contains all the possible API function. When we call a function, we pass the callback method as an anonymous function.

I am wondering how to do the same sort of thing in android. One method is to have the API class implement an interface with a processFinish function that the AsyncTask calls onPostExecute, but the implementation of processFinish would have a whole ton of conditions depending on which API function was called. How would I do this without making all these conditions?

Comment: This seems less android-centric and more a design pattern question for something like programmers.se, but if I were in your shoes I'd do it in a OOP way. Have a base function that is overridden by every type of API call and does its own thing.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi What exactly do you mean by overriding a base function? How would a determine which api call was calling the base function?

Comment: soon Java 8 will have Lambdas for this - hopefully the Droid will get them soon too.

Answer (score 0):

One analog to passing in callbacks that you may use for an api implementation on Android involves 'message looper' and 'handlers'.

A handler can be used inline like the way a function is passed as a callback. Handler implementations can be pretty robust Objects(runnable) as you can see from this async Http [example](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/).

In general, you can divide up your api into object hierarchy and when you 'obtain message' in android, you pass in the appropriate object and when the handler gets called back , it can call into the object(your api classes) provided earlier to the handler.

Take a quick look at 'defining a [handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)' and if it looks like it might work for you then focus on the advanced example using http in the previous link. Replace all the httpclient behavior with your api object hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for the input. It looks like Handlers and AsyncTasks are somewhat mutually exclusive, and I wanted to write as little thread related code as possible and therefore stick to AsyncTasks if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer I was looking for was anonymous functions